# SQL Agent Job not running, but fine within SSIS

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, db2, sql-agent-job

I have an SSIS job that uses a combination of ado and odbc connections pushing into a DB2 Database.
It runs fine locally, but when on the agent job, it specifically doesn't like one container.
The error output when ran is:

```
An error occurred executing the provided SQL command: (Lists the SQL script within that container). The package execution failed. The step failed
```

This script runs fine in both DB2, and when ran locally within SSIS, only fails within the agent job. Runs fine with this container disabled.

Steps I've tried to fix:

- Changed timeout to 0
- Recreated the connection
- Recreated the container
- Rebuilt and tried using the version within the dev folder
- Confirmed permissions are correct on the output table

Ran out of ideas at this point.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Since you say DB2, my instinct is 1) ensure the drivers are installed on the server 2) If they're installed, ensure your execution mode aligns with the driver bit-edness. By default, SSIS runs as 32 bit on your machine but 64 bit on server. IBM products generally only have 32 version of the drivers. Resolution on #2 is to go into advanced mode of job definition and check "Use 32 bit"

Comment: @billinkc Its completely inaccurate to say that IBM products “generally only have  32 [bit] versions of the drivers”